# Python: Write Logfile

Tags: python

I created an own class to open and write a linefile:

```
import os, datetime

class LogFile:

    def __init__(self, FileName):
        FilePath = "C:/MyDirectory/Log"
        self.__FileName = FileName
        self.__FullFileName = FilePath + "/" + self.__FileName
        if os.path.exists(self.__FullFileName):
            os.remove(self.__FullFileName)
        self.__File = open(self.__FullFileName,'a')
    def __del__(self):
        pass
    def openFile(self):        
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        time = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        self.__File.write(time + '/n')        
    def closeFile(self):
        self.__File.close
    def writeFile(self,Text):
        self.__File.write(Text)
```

It displays no error, opens the file, but does not write a line in my new file:

```
>>> import log
>>> from log import LogFile
>>> aa = LogFile("newbie")
>>> aa.openFile()
>>> aa.writeFile("newtext")
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: just `import logging` ...

Comment: @Reto There is already a `logging` module in Python for this kind of stuff, but if you want to reinvent the wheel as a learning experience, start from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is for learning, what you do is not so good.

You call your class Logfile, so I assume it is for logging in another application. One of the purpose of logs is precisely to get information when weird things happens, of when application crashes. So you should not buffer the informations logged, but flush them to disk as soon as possible.

You should considere to keep only the name of the file as attribute of the class, remove the open and close methods and change your writeFile to :

```
def writeFile(self,text):
    with open(self.__FullFileName) as fd:
        fd.write(text)
```

Of course, there is a serious overhead with repeated opening and closing the file, but also a strong gain in security of logs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close the opened file after writing. The content may be in the buffer. You will be able to see content after closing the file.

Or simply use python's `logging` module.